# The non-generic method 'ControllerBase.Ok()' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have asp.net core web api app where controller class is extend from `Controller : ControllerBase`, now I am getting error

> The non-generic method 'ControllerBase.Ok()' cannot be used with type arguments

for below api code, what's wrong here?

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<bool> Post()
    {
        return Ok<bool>(await _someTask);
    }
```

Based on below comment I implement like this ,

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Post()
    {
        return Ok(await SomeTask());
    }

    private async Task SomeTask()
    {
        //some database insert operation
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Then I am getting below error at `return Ok(await SomeTask());`,

> cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'Controller.cs  49  Active

Comment: `Ok<T>()` does not exist. Did you upgrade from an earlier aspnet core version?

Comment: No. it;s brand new asp.net core 3.1 web api app

Comment: @JohnWu Actually, it should return `Task<IActionResult>`, and the implementation of that `IActionResult` should be `ActionResult<bool>` - so the most descriptive return type would be `Task<ActionResult<bool>>`.

Comment: _Why_ do you want your action method to have the return type of `Task<bool>` or  `Task<ActionResult<bool>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `ControllerBase`'s `Ok` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_Ok_System_Object_) has two overloads: `Ok()` and `Ok(object)`

There's no generic overload and that's why you're getting your error message.

As a side note, though for this simplified version it's [perfectly fine to return a `Task<bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#specific-type), the more realistic scenario is that a method have more than one code path, or at least more than one expected output (for instance, it might return an 404 or 500 http status codes - for not found / internal server error).

In these cases, you want to return [`Task<ActionResult<T>>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1#actionresultt-type).
This way, when using tools like swagger to auto-generate your client code, you'll get a more suitable client for your api.

**Update**
Your `await` is misplaced.
Also, if you want to return a `bool`, then your other `async` method should return `Task<bool>`.

Try the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Post()
{
    var result = await SomeTask();
    return Ok(result);
}

private async Task<bool> SomeTask()
{
    //some database insert operation
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please check my comment `cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'Controller.cs 49 Active` on question while I tried to return `Task<ActionResult<bool>>`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Notice that mixing generic `ActionResult<T>` and `Ok() / StatusCode()` will not do what one would expect to. ActionResult converter doesn't seem to be able to decode non-generic Ok/StatusCode's and so doesn't fill `.Value` on the result correctly.

This doesn't matter when using the endpoint through the webserver but when you have unit/integration tests using direct object returns of the controllers, this is a nasty surprise.

Example:

```cs
public class Foo { }
class ExController: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult<Foo> ReturnOk()
        => Ok(new Foo());
    public ActionResult<Foo> ReturnObject()
        => new Foo();
    public ActionResult<Foo> ReturnStatusCode()
        => StatusCode(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status207MultiStatus, new Foo());
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestOk()
{
    var ctrl = new ExController();
    var rok = ctrl.ReturnOk();
    Assert.IsNull(rok.Value);  // ⚡
    Assert.IsNotNull(rok.Result);
    var oor = rok.Result as OkObjectResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(oor);
    Assert.IsNotNull(oor.Value);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(oor.Value, typeof(Foo));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestObject()
{
    var b = new ExController();
    var rok = b.ReturnObject();
    Assert.IsNotNull(rok.Value);
    Assert.IsNull(rok.Result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(rok.Value, typeof(Foo));
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestStatusCode()
{
    var ctrl = new ExController();
    var rsc = ctrl.ReturnStatusCode();
    Assert.IsNull(rsc.Value);  // ⚡
    Assert.IsNotNull(rsc.Result);
    var oor = rsc.Result as OkObjectResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(oor);
    Assert.IsNotNull(oor.Value);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(oor.Value, typeof(Foo));
}
```